# Does iCloud storage includes photos and videos?

Tags: icloud

Wikipedia says it doesn't.

However, iCloud it self say it does

> Your photos and videos are using 1.1 GB
>
> If you want to stop using iCloud Photos

Wikipedia said:

> While Photo Stream uses the iCloud servers, usage does not come out of
>   the user's iCloud storage allowance

Okay looks like there need to be some form of explanation

Answer (score 2):

Yes - this aspect could potentially be a little confusing. There **is** a difference between *iCloud Photo Library* and *PhotoStream* and backed up photos and videos.

### Photostream

- [Does not count](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201317) towards your iCloud storage limit.
- Contains up to 1000 pictures (and only pictures).
- Also, shared photo streams (now called Shared iCloud Photos) do not count towards your limit.
- PhotoStream has been around for awhile and is quite automatic. It uploads just photos and allows you to view those photos on your iPad or computer.

### iCloud Photo Library

- Counts towards your iCloud storage limit.
- Is in beta (as of March 2015)
- Must be manually enabled (and can sort of be disabled in Settings -> Photos & Camera -> iCloud Photo Library (Beta)).
- Uploads your *entire* photo and video library from your phone.
- Has some fancy-ness built in like optimizing your iOS device's storage.
- Can be viewed on your iPad, iPhone, computer, and iCloud.com
- Is terrible at this point (IMO, March 2015)

### Backed Up Photos

- Are managed in Settings -> iCloud -> Storage -> Manage Storage
- Typically they will then be under [Your iPhone Name]'s iPhone -> Photo Library, but if Photo Library is enabled you will see information on iCloud Photo Library.

[More general information.](http://www.apple.com/icloud/photos/)

Comment: This will, of course, continue to confuse the heck out of everybody for at least another year, if not beyond ;) Right now, I'd say, if it's not on your computer [& backed up regularly] it's not as safe as you thought it was.